# D3: Is it possible to prevent object to exit boundaries?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm having some troubles with d3 library.

I have some nodes with enabled force.drag() function. I want them to stay inside some squire. I have been trying this approach:

```
var force = d3.layout.force() 
    .size([w, h])
    .charge(-40) 
    .linkDistance(getLinkDistance)
    .gravity(0.01);

var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", onDragStart)
    .on("drag", onDrag);    

function onDragStart(d) {
    d.fixed = true;
}

function onDrag(d) {
    if (d.x < 0)
    d.x = 0;
    if (d.x > w)
    d.x = w;
    if (d.y < 0)
    d.y = 0;
    if (d.y > h)
    d.y = h;
}

 var newNodes = gnodes.enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; }) 
        .call(drag);
```

Unfortunately, the drag function seems to ignore this, and object still is able to exit the boundaries and become invisible. How can I prevent drag function to move objects outside my limits? To clarify, only dragging object must stay inside the squire, the rest can flay whatever they want.

Update:

I have partly solved the problem by adding dragend event and releasing the node there, if coordinates is wrong. Now the node will comeback from the outside of the screen at least. Still I can't manipulate it coordinates.

```
var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", onDragStart)
    .on("dragend", onDragEnd);


function onDragStart(d) {
    d.fixed = true;
}

function onDragEnd(d) {
    if (d.x < 0 || d.x > w || d.y < 0 || d.y > h)
    d.fixed = false;
}
```

Comment: It's not enough to change the data, you also need to update the DOM elements with the new positions.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff shouldn't force.drag() function do that automatically by calling update()?

Comment: The drag function won't call anything. You probably mean the `tick` handler function of the force layout -- in principle yes, but only if the layout is still running.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff It is running, how ether, coordinates do not updated. It seems what after node has been added to the svg, the x and y parameters of node object are just ignored.

Comment: Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff newer mind, just solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

Just solved that. Appears, the px and py coordinates need to be fixed:

```
var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", onDragStart)
    .on("drag", onDrag);

function validate(x, a, b) {
    if (x < a) x = a;
    if (x > b) x = b;
    return x;
}

function onDragStart(d) {
    d.fixed = true;
}

function onDrag(d) {
   d.px = validate(d.px, 0, w);
   d.py = validate(d.py, 0, h);
}
```

Comment: was able to use the `function validate(x, a, b)` from here with all the x and y changes in the `function ticked()` of a d3.forceSimulation

Comment: This saved my day